# Can't run a simple project (Maven - Spring - Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I'm new to Maven and Spring and I'm trying to use both with eclipse following a tutorial.
I created a simple webapp project with maven and made it suitable for eclipse. After the import of the project I'm not able to lunch it. Eclipse is not even recognizing errors in the code. Someone knows why?

My actual version of eclipse is 3.8.
My actual version of maven is 3.0.5.
OS ubuntu 14.04.
What I do is to lunch the following command from terminal:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=aevgui -DartifactId=GAEV -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

then I add the following lines into my pom:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

then from terminal:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and on one of the tries I used also this:

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace=/home/dario/workspace  eclipse:add-maven-repo
```

Now I'm able to import the project into eclipse directly from import project but this does not work. To be more clear: "does not work" means that eclipse is not compiling the code, it does not recognize new classes and errors in it, if I add a main method I'm not able to lunch it because eclipse can't find it.

What can I do?
Thank you.

Comment: As alternative, do you consider to do the whole process directly with the Eclipse? And as help (Spring integration with Eclipse), consider use http://spring.io/tools/sts

Comment: Ok I changed my version of ecliipse and also downloaded the plugin. Now i'm able to use spring.
Thank you.

Comment: I put the comment as answer. Accept it please and the thread can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative, do you consider to do the whole process directly with the Eclipse? And as help (Spring integration with Eclipse), consider use http://spring.io/tools/sts